# Results of group by null values are lost

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have table which has `productId` and `productVariantId` columns.

```
|id   |userId|productId|productVariantId|
----------------------------------------
|1    |1     |1        |1               |
|2    |1     |1        |2               |
|3    |1     |2        |56              |
|4    |1     |3        |(null)          |
|5    |2     |3        |(null)          |
|6    |1     |4        |(null)          |
|7    |2     |1        |1               |
...
```

`productId` and `productVariantId` are related to `product` and `productVariant` tables respectively (many to one). Some products has no variants, so `productVariantId` might be `null`. I should select all distinct products with variants. Variants of products should be considered as distinct. But, my query is not selecting rows with null valued `productVariantId`s.

I have used `group by pt.product, productVariant`. This works perfectly only when `productVariantId` is not null.

```
@Query("select new com.package.name.dto.ProductTG(pt.product, pt.productVariant, concat(:language))" +
        "from ProductT pt " +
        "where :language=:language " +
        "and (:productName = 'ALL' " +
        "or (upper(pt.product.nameEng) like upper(concat('%',:productName, '%'))) " +
        "or (upper(pt.product.nameRus) like upper(concat('%',:productName, '%')))) " +
        "group by pt.product, pt.productVariant")
    List<ProductTG> findAllProductTs(@Param("productName") String productName, @Param("language") String language);
```

This query selects

```
-------------------------------
|id|productId|productVariantId|
-------------------------------
|1 |1        |1               |
|2 |1        |2               |
|3 |2        |56              |
-------------------------------
```

However, I am expecting this one:

```
-------------------------------
|id|productId|productVariantId|
-------------------------------
|1 |1        |1               |
|2 |1        |2               |
|3 |2        |56              |
|4 |3        |(null)          |
|6 |4        |(null)          |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: I assume, that `pt.productVariant` refers to another class which is only identified by `productVariantId`. Therefore you should probably group on `pt.productVariant.id` ot something like that

Comment: this not helped :-)

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your post and include the specific brand (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc) and version you are using.

Comment: Do you check pt.product.nameEn, pt.product.nameRus and productName value and result of condition related to them?

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have an inner join going on. What happens when you do "All"?

Comment: `select distinct productId,productVariantId from ProductT`

Comment: @shawnt00 I have field for searching product by its name. When "ALL" it will not check `like` condition. Yes, I should use another word, because I have some products which name contains word 'all'. Thank you for this

Comment: My question was does the "All" feature even work right?